# Increase the font size on Sublime Text 2 status bar?

Tags: sublime-text-2, ide

Is it possible to increase the font size on the Sublime Text `status bar`?  I did some searching and didn't find much at all on the subject.  I sometimes miss important information displayed in the `status bar` simply because its so small I don't notice it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select *Browse Packages…* (menu location is OS-dependent, it's in *Sublime Text 2 » Preferences* on OS X), and enter the *Theme - Default* directory. Edit *Default.sublime-theme* to set a `font.size` value for the element with `"class": "label_control"`, e.g. like the following:

```
{
    "class": "label_control",
    "color": [255, 255, 255],
    "shadow_color": [24, 24, 24],
    "shadow_offset": [0, -1],
    "font.size": 18.0
},
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot of large status bar]

If you installed other themes, you need to change them instead, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question, but I had a similar problem where all the text was too small; status bar, tabs, folder/file tree etc.
The answer was to add `"dpi_scale": 2.0` to my Sublime Prefs, as detailed [here](http://b.wardje.eu/2014/08/sublime-text-3-and-high-dpi-on-linux.html)

> so you can just go ahead and open your user preferences (Preferences > Settings - User). Next, add the following line: `"dpi_scale": 2.0`. If you haven't yet changed settings here before, the file has to follow the JSON format, so be sure to place the appropriate commas. After adding the line, save the file.
>   With the setting changed and saved, just restart Sublime Text.

Comment: Could you quote the relevant parts from your link? This is in case the link is edited or removed in the future. Please take our [tour] or read [answer].

Comment: um, I have: *The answer was to add "dpi_scale": 2.0 to my Sublime Prefs*

Comment: @bordeltabernacle You might want to quote the rest of the instructions ... it's only 2 paragraphs ...